# Revert Flow Free puzzle

Tags: code-golf, array, grid, path-finding

*Inspired by [Is this Flow Free puzzle trivial?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235848/is-this-flow-free-puzzle-trivial) by [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler). Lengthy chunks of this challenge are borrowed from there. This may be one step of a solution for the linked challenge, depending on chosen strategy.*

### Background

*Flow Free* is a series of puzzle games whose objective is to connect all the same-colored pairs of dots on the grid. In this challenge, we consider the original game on a rectangular grid (no variations like bridges, warps, or hexagonal grids).

A puzzle in *Flow Free* might look like this:

```
Puzzle   Solution
....1    11111
.....    13333
..24.    13243
1....    13243
23...    23243
...43    22243
```

### Challenge

Given a solved Flow Free puzzle, output the unsolved puzzle.

The input can be taken as a single string/array or a list of lines. You may also take the dimensions of the array as input.

You may assume only the digits 1-9 are used and the numbers used in the solved puzzle will be a strict prefix of these (i.e. no need to handle there being `2`s but no `1`s in the input). Also, each line represented by each digit is a valid [polystrip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/155983/78410) of length 3 or higher.

Unsolving means identifying the ends of the polystrips and keeping them in place, while replacing other cells with a `0` or any consistent non-digit character.

Output the string/array in any convenient manner.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code per language wins!

### Test cases

| Inputs | Outputs |
| --- | --- |
| ``` 11111 12221 11113 33333 32222 11111 13333 13243 13243 23243 22243 11121 13121 13121 13111 11122 13121 13121 33111 13333 13443 13343 11243 21243 22244 1116777 1226666 1125555 5555344 8888334 9998444 ``` | ``` ..... 12.21 1..13 ..... 32..2 ....1 ..... ..24. 1.... 23... ...43 ...21 .3... ...2. 13... ....2 .3..1 1..2. 3.... 1.... ..4.. ..3.. ..2.. 21..3 ....4 ..167.7 .2....6 .12...5 5...34. 8....3. 9.984.. ``` |

Comment: "You may assume only the digits 1-9 are used", I would imagine we may assume that the numbers used in the solved puzzle will be a strict prefix of these (i.e. we do not need to handle there being `2`s but no `1`s in the input etc.), is that correct?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I didn't mean that there, but you may assume that, if that fits you.

Comment: I did not believe you meant that, but that if I asked you would say OK. I don't think I'd need it though, but it could be a useful allowance for some.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>87 84 83</s>  82 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

Expects a matrix of integers. Returns another matrix where empty cells are set to `0`.

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v*-(g=d=>d+2?((m[y+d--%2]||0)[x+d%2]==v)+g(d):d)(2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7JTsMwEL37K6xIKB7SuI0TuoAcTnDk0mPbQ4idkCobThq1onx7sZ1WwDs8zcxbNPtkSLpUFW3v142Ql4xfKh5XtEpaQtTkBDxW4zJMjnoZ7n2Sc8Fj4bFnQqrNyRO@f8d25/MMNkdP6JHzAbycCHgUQBgAXJT8PBRKEjfrXKBKJuK1KOX6VKdkBrRv1r0q6pwA7dqy6Imzrbe1AzRr1EuSfpAO8xh/IYwrzHH3a9IW85qVN5TSbmf3t0P1LhXAk06kTd01paRlk5OMVGNAmYCi@6aoieMAXCdbqGRbJqkk09k0n2CXuoA9bCX0DZfAAAWMsQAhM4coNEChPrHxpHV7CkIW3ZiNzAwbEzOmfxyMhbrkrxBehWthZAtDw4EtDG61kU3PF4uF@W6uYSwPGsiQTqKlhs6i1Wq1jKLoBw)

Or **79 bytes** with optional chaining:

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v*-(g=d=>d+2?(m[y+d--%2]?.[x+d%2]==v)+g(d):d)(2)))
```

(not supported by TIO)

#### Commented

```javascript
m =>                       // m[] = input matrix
m.map((r, y) =>            // for each row r[] at position y in m[]:
  r.map((v, x) =>          //   for each value v at position x in r[]:
    v * -(                 //     set v to 0 if the result of g() is 0
                           //     or leave it unchanged if it's -1
      g =                  //     g is a recursive function taking
      d =>                 //     a direction d in [-1, 0, 1, 2]
      d + 2 ?              //       if d is not equal to -2:
        (                  //         we test whether the adjacent cell
          (                //         at (x', y') with:
            m[y + d-- % 2] //           y' = y + (d % 2)
            || 0           //
          )                //
          [x + d % 2]      //           x' = x + ((d - 1) % 2)
          == v             //         is equal to v
        )                  //         and increment the result if it is
        + g(d)             //         recursive call
      :                    //       else:
        d                  //         stop the recursion and subtract 2
    )(2)                   //     initial call to g with d = 2
  )                        //   end of inner map()
)                          // end of outer map()
```

Comment: `m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v*-(g=d=>d+2?((m[y+d--%2]||0)[x+d%2]==v)+g(d):d)(2)))`

Comment: @tsh Oh I see. I overlooked the part _valid polystrip of length 3 or higher_, which implies that there will never be more than 2 neighbors. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 106 bytes

```
ArrayFilter[Count[Extract[#,{{1,2},{2,1},{2,3},{3,2}}],#[[2,2]]]/.{1->#[[2,2]],_->0}&,#,{1,1},Padding->0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9Na8MwDIb/iws5Kcss77iFjrLeBoXs5pjhNe5qSJ3garBh8tszucmYDnrR41cfvlg6u4slf7Tz6Wl@jtH@7H1PLurd8BVIv3xTtEfSG0hJAk6QEOQtK86KyWRgozUCGmOquyTL@q@E97K@nwrgXpmbDrbrfPhkaIo5CZmjDRIRpYBbqdqgcrAwxZVm00Klwod/wVWQRUxV9WpHvTvbfK@L121Dkbc1Y@/z@aINwhRmcR34Jf9tHCItNn3asufNfvSOt@6967vGjTyLhngVZS2EeazXGfMv)

```
ArrayFilter[                       -apply to each 3x3 block, padded with 0s
  Count[                           -count the
    Extract[#,                     -occurrences at
      {{1,2},{2,1},{2,3},{3,2}}    -positions up, down, left, right
    ],
    #[[2,2]]                       -of the center element
  ]
  /.{1->#[[2,2]],_->0}&,           -replace with center element if count is 1, otherwise 0
#,{1,1},Padding->0]&
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 51 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υιυＵＭυ⪪ι¹ＦＬυ«Ｊ⁰ιＦＬ§υι«Ｆ⊖№ＫＶＫＫ§≔§υικ.→»»Ｊ⁰¦⁰Ｅυ⪫ιω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU9BboMwEDzjV1g52ZIbxUBDaE5ReknUVKipekewAStgI7CTSlXeTtdCbdo9WN6dnZmdos77wuTNOF5r1QBlO905e7S90hXjnGZuqJkTVPE1yXBomcPfIe@2pm1zXXrs2DXKMiWo5IidTE/ZC@jKIhEVvkiwd233bthikgn@bmzsTpfwOVlM2xP@DEUPLWgLJdsah8YZwPnD6FdwaKwZF9RP8EikbYZBVfpH7J@ooGdBZ/OZdw4O5gLs6U1VtfX9jdzI/bjFb0bM58l7o7TPdUWL9ThKKZdJkhAZhkssImX4iEX8E8UxWWFFUUzSNF3F2I8Pl@Yb) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a newline-terminated list of strings of digits. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιυ
```

Input the strings and print them to the canvas.

```
ＵＭυ⪪ι¹
```

Split the strings into character lists so that they can be replaced.

```
ＦＬυ«
```

Loop over each of the lists.

```
Ｊ⁰ι
```

Jump to the start of its line.

```
ＦＬ§υι«
```

Loop over the cells of the list.

```
Ｆ⊖№ＫＶＫＫ§≔§υικ.
```

Count the number of times the cell appears in its Von Neumann neighbourhood. If it's more than once then replace the state with a `.`.

```
→
```

Move to the next cell.

```
»»Ｊ⁰¦⁰Ｅυ⪫ιω
```

Overwrite the canvas with the new states.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 125 bytes

```
(.)(?<=(\1).)?(?=(?<2>\1))?(?<=(?<!.)(?(3)$)(?<-3>.)*(?<2>\1).*¶(.)*.)?(?=(?<=(.)*.).*¶(?<-4>.)*(?(4)$)(?<2>\1))?(?<-2>){2}
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU45DsIwEOz3F0gg2VFiaQ9ySDkeQUsBBQUNBaJDfCsPyMfCrp1wTDHe2Z0Z@X55XG/neRohh8Mpz2Hn9Jld8G5oO3dEH/zghk4V9apMtKY25nDst2YsuA8@Wz0hm0YtyD7JLqm4V7Mks5MU/vYW1PsnvSDM/hR/pDSNyzSjAZCIEMBmBjYA64rSSu9xhUyyMiUmYzORmf4YU6GW/B54OSyFEgvZGGMhrrUS02VVVfa7UmGWvQKMNAm1QrPQNE0tIm8) Link includes test suite that splits on double-spaced tests and double-spaces the results. Explanation:

```
(.)
```

Match a character...

```
(?<=(\1).)?
```

... that might be preceded by a copy of that character, ...

```
(?=(?<2>\1))?
```

... that might be followed by a copy of that character, reusing capture group 2 for the count of copies, ...

```
(?<=(?<!.)(?(3)$)(?<-3>.)*(?<2>\1).*¶(.)*.)?
```

... that might be below a copy of that character, using a .NET balancing group to ensure both characters are in the same column, ...

```
(?=(?<=(.)*.).*¶(?<-4>.)*(?(4)$)(?<2>\1))?
```

... or that might be above a copy of that character, ...

```
(?<-2>){2}
```

... where two copies exist.

```
.
```

Replace it with a dot.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 111 bytes

```python
lambda k:[c*(sum('0'<c==(k+" "*d)[n+q]for d in(1,k.find('\n')+1)for q in(d,-d))<2)or'.'for n,c in enumerate(k)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/LcoIwFN3nKzJukoh1mgRFrXRnt/0A6wIhjCkYMOK0fj29N2htzwwH5rzm0l67Q@N0X6YffZ0d90VGq9U2H/Pz5cjZM1vnacqraERH40JsXXTalY2nBbWOy0k1La0rOPtwTERSoHNCp5g8FUKslWg8mzKU3SQHgxp3ORqfdYZXYtdb19KUMka@DrY2VK4IpZ2/4ovS2joDLmQuHRdBsuWgvkJnCFH0aZQGPcI7gmzqs7kHWm9dxxmbfjZwWcmhIIR4edRThiXznZu2o5v3t433jR/ae2@yqpcIIpVSkhD81kQjiAZJDRL4QZJaxXdWAytkDCkM/WM5DMLIX0PfjNtgHAY1sgyD8j4bh/Y8SRK8bg7AyAxAkKBJFgDokuVyuYhDQenfB9s4hL9DSALS7MEgJzAOHD@Y/AA)

Returns a list of characters.

-1 byte thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)

Thanks to [PertinentDetail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103228/pertinentdetail) for fixing a bug for only +3 bytes

Comment: [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU7LcoIwFN3nK@4uSbFOk1AfVLqz236AukAIYwoGjDitX0/vBZ3asziE85rbXrtD401fptu@zo77IoMq2eRP4nw5Cv7CV3maVhsfnZLdJlG7sglQgPNCTapp6Xwh@NZzGSlJzomcYvJcSLnSsgl8ykn2kxwNsP5ytCHrrKjkrne@hRQ4Z98HV1tQCQPowpU@ALXzFl3MXDohB8mVo/qOnTEE5EOUDnpEdwyyrc/2HmiD853gfPrV4GWlwIKU8u2vnnIq2Z/cth2sPz/WITRhbO@DzapeEZjSWivG6G2YITCDkh4l9AdJGR3fWY@siSmkKfSP1TiII4@GuRm3wXgYNMRqGFT32Xhoz@bzOV03Q1DkFcGIsMkWCOyy5XK5iPH/Fw) as a lambda function

Comment: This fails on the fourth test case. The failure is more obvious on `"123\n123\n123\n"`. I can [fix it](https://tio.run/##VU/LcoIwFN3nKzJukoh1mgRFrXRnt/0A6wIhjCkYMOK0fj29N2htzwwH5rzm0l67Q@N0X6YffZ0d90VGq9U2H/Pz5cjZM1vnacqraERH40JsXXTalY2nBbWOy0k1La0rOPtwTERSoHNCp5g8FUKslWg8mzKU3SQHgxp3ORqfdYZXYtdb19KUMka@DrY2VK4IpZ2/4ovS2joDLmQuHRdBsuWgvkJnCFH0aZQGPcI7gmzqs7kHWm9dxxmbfjZwWcmhIIR4edRThiXznZu2o5v3t433jR/ae2@yqpcIIpVSkhD81kQjiAZJDRL4QZJaxXdWAytkDCkM/WM5DMLIX0PfjNtgHAY1sgyD8j4bh/Y8SRK8bg7AyAxAkKBJFgDokuVyuYhDQenfB9s4hL9DSALS7MEgJzAOHD@Y/AA) at the cost of growing to 111 characters.

Comment: @ovs Great find, thanks!

Comment: @PertinentDetail Ah, I missed that. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒĠạⱮ§ỊSʋÐṀ⁸$€ẎŒṬ¬a
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of list of positive integers and yields a list of lists of non-negative integers (`0` representing the unclued cells).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCMLHu5a@GjjukPLH@7uCj7VfXjCw51Njxp3qDxqWvNwV9/RSQ93rtE@tCbx////0dGGOgoQZKajYA5BsToKIGEjMDKDI6gwRMYUjkDCpkgCxjoKJkAEErbQUYAjY4gMSNhSRwGCLCBKQcKxAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCMLHu5a@GjjukPLH@7uCj7VfXjCw51Njxp3qDxqWvNwV9/RSQ93rtE@tCbx/9HJD3cuftS479A2INz6cPeWMKAKIDrcnv@oYa5epGYWVPL/f3V19RguQxDgMjQyMjLkAnOMuYxBgMsYKGTEBZMHCxkaG5nASCMIaQQiQYqMQIpQSEOIgUBDkCWMoRJQA03ABhqDSEOwgYYwY03Aus3Mzc1BrjMDApASUyDgAhFAnVwWQADUy2VpaWlhYmIC9A8A).

#### How?

```
ŒĠạⱮ§ỊSʋÐṀ⁸$€ẎŒṬ¬a - Link: list of lists, A
ŒĠ                 - group multi-dimensional indices by their values
            €      - for each group (a list of coordinates, G, where one of the values are):
           $       -   last two links as a monad, f(G):
          ⁸        -     using G as the right argument...
        ÐṀ         -     filter G keeping those [a,b] which are maximal under:
       ʋ           -       last four links as a dyad, f([a,b], G)
   Ɱ               -         map across G with:
  ạ                -           absolute difference (vectorises)
    §              -           sums (-> Manhatten distances)
     Ị             -           insignificant? (0 or 1?)
      S            -           sum
             Ẏ     - tighten to a list of coordinates (of the blanks in the puzzle)
              ŒṬ   - multi-dimensional untruth
                ¬  - logical NOT (vectorises)
                 a - logical AND with A (vectorises)
```

Comment: If the tightened list of coordinates doesn't include the last row or column, does 'multi-dimensional untruth' fill a big-enough matrix?  For instance, [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCMLHu5a@GjjukPLH@7uCj7VfXjCw51Njxp3qDxqWvNwV9/RSQ93rkn8//9/dLSxDgga6RjqGMbqRBvpQKAJmGeiA4MgnqGOKRRCeHAYGwsA) seems to fail...

Comment: Huh, I thought it would be OK... will delete/fix

Comment: Thanks, fixed it up now!

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 112 bytes

```r
function(m)m*(apply(which(m|1,T),1,function(j)sum(m[t((j+rbind(o<-c(1:-1,0),rev(o)))%%(dim(m)+1))]==m[t(j)]))<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/LDoIwEEX3/Q@SGR0SW3zH/gU740JAY4mlpoJI4r9ji2A0xpzNSWdub2vbqria8@2QyfZYFWmpTAEa9Qj2l8u5gfqk0hPoB6cYidN7JcdrpUFvS4B8bBNVZGA2YQp8HXKaINnDDQwiBgFkyi3imCPupPSJHHeIG4GtlnpfWnUHlyPPnBYdjJNwzHuYnwma9bBBIpo62JJeRN0BW5Fn2c2m6OJJY00tY2TDV91zGPsp97imqKdT4e74VvGp4qX/Ston)

```r
unsolved=function(m)                # get unsolved puzzle for matrix m:                 
 m*                                 # m multiplied by...
  (apply(which(m|1,T),1,function(j) # function applied to all coordinates of m:
    sum(m[                          #  sum of elements of m...
     t((j                           #  at each coordinate...
      +rbind(o<-c(1:-1,0),rev(o)))  #  plus (1,0),(0,-1),(-1,0) & (0,1)...
     %%(dim(m)+1))                  #  modulo dimensions of m +1...
                                    #  (prevents offset coordinates becoming too big)
    ]==m[t(j)]))                    #  that are equal to the value at this coordinate
  <2)                               # is less than 2 
                                    # (so, is equal to 1, since there are no 'lonely' 
                                    # digits without any equal neighbours as each line 
                                    # is guaranteed to be length 3 or longer)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)

```
4⊸⊑⊸(⊣×1=·+´1‿3‿5‿7⊏=)∘⥊⎉2 3‿3↕⊢↑˝·≍⟜¬2+≢
```

[Try it here.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=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)

It is a tacit function which takes input as an integer array and returns an integer array. The function can be split into three parts:

Pad the input with 0s on all sides.

```
⊢↑˝·≍⟜¬2+≢ #
       2+≢ # Add 2 to each dimension of the shape
⊢↑˝·≍⟜¬    # and use that to over-take from the input in each direction
```

Make a rank 4 array of the 3 by 3 windows.

```
3‿3↕
```

Replace each window with it's center element if it is an endpoint, otherwise replace with 0.

```
4⊸⊑⊸(⊣×1=·+´1‿3‿5‿7⊏=)∘⥊⎉2 # 
                        ⎉2 # On the rank 2 subarrays:
                      ∘⥊   # flatten
4⊸⊑                        # get the center element,
   ⊸(                )     # and pass as the left argument into the train:
                    =      # compare equality of flattened window with center
            1‿3‿5‿7⊏       # pick out only the Manhattan neighbors
         ·+´               # sum the true values
       1=                  # test if equals 1,
     ⊣×                    # and multiply bool result by the center element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 170 bytes

```ruby
->m{(0...R=m.size).map{|y|(0...C=m[0].size).map{|x|[[y-1,x],[y,x-1],[y+1,x],[y,x+1]].reject{|a,b|a<0||a>=R||b<0||b>=C}.map{|a,b|m[y][x]==m[a][b]?1:0}.sum<2?m[y][x]:'.'}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHbjoIwEH3vV0yIiRqwoYX1FtEH/8DXpg@gkMVYNYAJLOXb2da6gNnsTtJwzsyZmdOSPaKqHSVBO9uKeuJijA@BwHn6FU@xCO@1rOQzuw8Ec/mwUErGqhlxSu6wyilnRH/tjtuEc5zF5/hY1DJ0IhluXCnDbXCQMtIw2gb7xozSZcEqzkoeqD0hZxHfkbXb4PwhNnT3qq3HeNw0TXuKEyjivJiIKYIsGCX4GF4uT5bcMkghvYL2bO6BAO6PIgfBUg42WADq2JApis@39Iogvp6Q0VgWUgQQQoxZRIflqH6LUEqJxR2EwOQ9k/d0vKCS0KHkp7WXEI/6vyEdQKphP4N2M/6AZGhKrf9H7b2ph6b83pTXQdKbIm/@/MHG@WKx6B5orqJr/lBhiEZqhSFLFWqJIavVaunreRzH4fGzlkK@/mrTfgM)

- Straightforward approach : we cross check every element against the 4 adjacent elements and we keep it if there are only 1, we put a dot instead.
- to check adjacent elements we build an array of [y,x] indexes and we reject pairs out of bounds, this costs so many bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [Matlab](https://au.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), <s>102</s> 90 bytes

```matlab
function a=f(a)
for i=1:9
b=a==i
a=a-b.*(conv2(b,[0 1 0;1 0 1;0 1 0],'same')~=1)*i
end
end
```

The input is *a* and the output is also *a*. This goes through all the values in the grid (1 to 9). For each value it finds cells that have more than one neighbor of that value. This is done using the 4-directional 2D convolution conv2. It then sets those cells to 0. What is left is the required grid. Note this will also work if there are multiple paths with the same digit. It also works for the case when digit 1 is missing, but digit 2 exists.

-12 bytes by removing unnecessary white space. Thanks to @MarcMush!

Comment: I haven't golfed (or used even) Matlab in like [5 years](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103859/55372), but you may have a look at the Matlab tips question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12974/tips-for-golfing-in-matlab

Comment: Assuming input in a variable is not allowed, so you need to wrap it into a function (taking `a` as a parameter and returning the modified `a` at the end; linking a valid [example answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58387/78410) because I don't actually know matlab).

Comment: Thank you both. I will try to fix it.

Comment: I wrapped it in a function, so this submission is legal now. Still shorter than most non-golfing languages :)

Comment: you can save at least 15 bytes by removing all the useless spaces