# Follow the border

Tags: code-golf, array, path-finding

*Inspired by [Is this Flow Free puzzle trivial?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/235848/is-this-flow-free-puzzle-trivial) by [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler). Lengthy chunks of this challenge are borrowed from there. This may be one step of a solution for the linked challenge, depending on chosen strategy.*

### Challenge

Given an array of digits `1-9` and a padding character of your choice, output the border of the shape made by the digits (in any direction, with any starting point).

#### Example

Here, the padding character is `0`.

```
Input   Border  Output (one of possible)
00111   00###   111334442222211133
13333   ###3#   
13243   #32##   
13240   #32#0   
23240   #3##0   
22200   ###00
```

### Rules

The input can be taken as a single string/array or a list of lines. You may also take the dimensions of the array as input.

The input shape will be guaranteed to be at least 2 cells thick (so no overlapping borders) and will be interconnected (so one continuous border).

You may assume only the digits 1-9 are used and choose the padding character to be either `0` or any consistent non-digit one. You may omit the trailing padding in the input and assume the array will have minimal dimensions to fit the shape (so no column or row full of `0` will be provided).

Output the string/list in any convenient manner.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code per language wins!

### Test cases

Here, the padding character is `0`. Outputs here start at the leftmost cell of first row, but rotations and reflections of that vector are fine.

```
00111
13333
13243
13240
23240
22200
Output: 111334442222211133

11111
13331
12221
Output: 111111122211

00110
33333
32222
Output: 113322223333

00330
03240
13243
23243
22043
Output: 334433344232221332

0000777
0006666
0025550
0555300
8888000
9990000
Output: 7776655358899988552566

123456
789876
540032
120000
345678
987654
Output: 123456623789842456784567893157
```

Comment: May I assume no extra padded 0's are given? For example, not `00000 11111 13331 12221` nor `011111 013331 012221`.

Comment: @tsh *"the array will have minimal dimensions to fit the shape (so no column or row full of 0 will be provided)"*

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>116</s>  101 bytes

Expects a list of strings, using any non-digit character for padding. Returns a string.

```javascript
a=>(g=X=>+(d&=3,v=(a[y=Y+--d%2]||0)[x=X+~-d%2])?x-q|y?v+g(x,Y=y):v:g(X,d+=2))(q=a[d=Y=0].search`\\d`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9NjtowFN77FBZSG1vBEbHj/FAZVu22i9mAAGksYpiMogSSgEClPUGlbrps79HzzAV6BObZEcO8xWf5fT/vvWd91O26KXYdq@rcXDfqqtWEbNVMTXySf1RieFREL85q7jOWf@Cry2VEFyc183@4L52e2P5ynh79LTkN5@pMx8fxlsyGua84pWSv9CJXczVaBa3RzfrpcbnMH@m1MftD0RjibVqPBo3R@ZeiNA/nak1GNOjqh64pqi2hQbsri44MltWyGtBgUzef9fqJtFhN8DeEcWk6rLHC7V04oEMgbNVA6GBX7@45GEJc46ZpDGThDdH0E4LWuq7aujRBWW8JUMOeV3gRBEG9gkWPpmkN5D3XRUU8j@Ip9v7/@/Xy5zegh8fYe/n704Ow7/TKWBiGKBRQgDzqkSHeI@eMoa@HbnfoxhiUQkRRxG25D0JhePMD2vZ7tS0nRcjOYUi4OcL63@mEazgKdEIwxNz0fh/eI2eAN49dQ1jg1moDrJOxJEnsG0PBy6WUkAUo4IoUCjiUZZmVvmWBJ45BItMUqDSVkkuwwzUikjFK0ixNYiQj2IxD03ktk6TIMjK6X@IcMRfWE3GncZCJUCav)

#### How?

This algorithm starts at the leftmost non-empty cell on the first row of the grid and goes counterclockwise from there, leading to the outputs provided in the test cases in reverse order.

The recursive function \$g\$ takes a position \$(X,Y)\$ and a direction \$d\$. (NB: \$Y\$ and \$d\$ are global variables. Only \$X\$ is passed explicitly.)

We first look for the smallest \$q\ge0\$ such that the cell at \$(q,0)\$ is not empty and do an initial call to \$g\$ with \$(X,Y)=(q,0)\$ and \$d=0\$.

Within the function \$g\$:

1. We force \$d\$ into \$[0,1,2,3]\$ by isolating the two least significant bits, and we decrement it afterwards.
2. We advance by one square to a new position \$(x,y)\$, according to the updated value of \$d\$:

   - \$-1\$ = north
   - \$0\$ = west
   - \$1\$ = south
   - \$2\$ = east
3. If we've just reached \$(q,0)\$, the border is complete. We append the last value and stop.
4. Otherwise, we do a recursive call:

   - If the cell at our new position is non-empty, we append the value of the cell to the final result and process the recursive call `g(x,Y=y)`. Because \$d\$ was decremented at step 1, it means that we do a 90° turn to the right.
   - Otherwise, we process the recursive call `g(X,d+=2)`, which means that we rollback to the previous position and do a 90° turn to the left.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>82</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
ＷＳ⟦ι⟧Ｊ⌕⭆θ¬Σι0⁰≔⁰θＷ¬⁼0ＫＫ«⊞υＫＫ≦⊕θＷ›0§ＫＶ⁻¹θ≦⊖θ✳⊗θ0»⎚↑υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BS8QwEIXPza8Ie5pAhbZ6sqfFVamwS2HVi3iI7bANpkmbJiqIv71OSVVwDo/J8OZ7maaTrrFSz/N7pzRyqMwQ/NE7ZU4gBK@p8fCknkXJ7kI/3Fu4UaaF6NjLAcaUH6yHY@hBCSFSvsk2pBktbKdJnQxkKR/ptQYs5usxSD0BOVNeI75SEmV9sqQOUwfhd1iyhCJWTGUahz0aj20EJivx1qH06CJu6yvT4gcshEdrDhh6aQzQj/bKhAnyZXdJ@wPv8D84Xr1TDhuvLDlseNHYwvhzX8m@2JVG6YDa6L58GFIeRDnPnOd5zvJzKtLiIipnRdSi4JzNZ2/6Gw) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses space as the padding character. Edit: Saved <s>29</s> 31 bytes by realising that the border end could be detected without deleting the interior. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⟦ι⟧
```

Print the input to the canvas.

```
Ｊ⌕⭆θ¬Σι0⁰
```

Find the first digit in the first row.

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start moving horizontally.

```
Ｗ¬⁼0ＫＫ«
```

Repeat until the border has been traversed.

```
⊞υＫＫ
```

Append the next border cell to the result.

```
≦⊕θ
```

Try rotating left.

```
Ｗ›0§ＫＶ⁻¹θ≦⊖θ
```

Rotate right if necessary until a digit is found.

```
✳⊗θ0
```

Move in that direction, erasing the current border.

```
»⎚↑υ
```

Output the final result.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 307 bytes

```py
E=enumerate
M=[(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0)]
def f(b):
 d={(x,y):v for x,r in E(b)for y,v in E(r)}
 T=[]
 for x,y in d:
  if d[(x,y)]and any((x+X,y+Y)not in d or not d[(x+X,y+Y)]for X,Y in M):T+=[d[(x,y)]]
  if 0==d[(x,y)]:T+=[d[J]for X,Y in[(1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1),(-1,1)]if(J:=(x+X,y+Y))in d and d[J]]
 return T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVI9b4MwFNz9K6wstRun8gcEEsljl0rtlKEVRRUVoCK1BhlaBVX97el7mEQZ8HDGd/fOz9jdOHy0zqSdP53ubeW@vypfDBV5tBmTQnEBuMFJCQm4wSknZVXTmr3zPaGl/WVHMfL9D61bT4/C08bRexBxOYqfsPT8j9CDzXIy20bkSwigTU3LbMrIC1fSwo2MHdfPYly/cNcOk49CDX6jcZZyzHkWL6g/8v1hbbNzTB5SpbVnZpYfrooyOJIKR5oPuJmXiudNzR729rIXn3rA7jAD4n01fHtHD6eeWrparYiUSimiDAxAHQWURAfUWkqCvl7NBUqdCwBBV0HWV3mSmCnPgKyDbC6yMZLIKTxspwNqCThZo4tVyiRJcN7CgFnHcQzFgAa6SmGARna7HVpDcXzuUpso3pIk3aXJlsQR7KuBnIyoJClBJY6mMnwWQ/v23ha@ZD2@jvk/ZdntV9Gxxg2iCRfX4LXVzedQefbUukrQ/q7vPpuB3by6Gw5vjHQe/KxmV4mcL7BqmdbLtFmmo2U6Bvr0Dw)